# Is it possible to influence an online quantum random number generator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers

Suppose that I download quantum random numbers from the internet, for example from [here](https://quantumnumbers.anu.edu.au/). For example, I could sample values $X_1,X_2,…$ of a normal distribution. Now if I make the sample size large enough, it will be approximately normally distributed.

However, in quantum mechanics there is the [observer effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)). In certain situations, particles can be influenced by observing them.

Can I use this principle in some way, maybe using extra devices or by measuring the information in some special order, to influence the outputs $X_1,…$? By influencing I mean, that they have a different distribution for large sample size.

If this is impossible, why would that be?

To clarify, this question is not about going to the source of the random numbers and influencing it there. Instead, the numbers should first be downloaded to my laptop and then be influenced by some process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible because you are not the "observer" in the quantum mechanical sense here. The observer is the machine that directly makes measurements of the quantum system. All the quantum stuff stops here. Everything that happens after that, post processing at the server end, sending the data over the Internet, storing it on your computer, etc. is handling purely classical data and anything related to the observer effect is long gone

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the system (qRNG + observing machine) does not have a wave function because it is classical? Does this then also apply tothe Schrödingers cat paradox? That would then mean that is does not actually apply to cats. And a system (quantum process + cat) does not have a wave function because it is macroscopic?

Comment: Also, in the Wigner’s friend thought experiment, Wigner assigns a wavefunction to a system (laboratory + quantum measurement). Doesn’t this imply that the system (measurement device + quantum random process) als has a wave function, to which we could apply observer effect-ish techniques?

Comment: We still do not fully understand when a measurement takes place or what exactly happens. Having said that we do understand it well enough for all practical applications. Large objects interacting with their environment certainly behave classically. What happens to large objects that are isolated from their environment (a la Schrodinger's cat or Wigner's friend) is still debated, as practically we cannot engineer such setups. Small systems that are interacting with their environment are an area of active research but we are increasingly starting to understand how classical behavior emerges.

Comment: So the machine that observes the quantum random system is certainly not made in a way that it does not communicate with its environment, and therefore we are sure that the combined system behaves classically.

Answer (score 1):

> ... the numbers should first be downloaded to my laptop and then be influenced by some process

There is nothing in the observer effect that suggests you can influence the result of a measurement of a quantum system *after the measurement has taken place*. Even in [delayed choice experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%27s_delayed-choice_experiment) the change in the experimental apparatus occurs *before* the final measurement takes place.